# Old image fileformat

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

I need some suggestion on how to convert Leadtools CMP image format to something abit more modern...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to their website, they have a [non-free SDK](http://www.leadtools.com/sdk/imaging.htm) that will do what you need.

A "ghetto" method might be to display the image and then use a screen-grab utility to capture the image.