# Convert CMP images to common types like JPG

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing

I'm seeking some help in converting images in CMP format to common formats like JPG or PNG.

Online tools [like this](https://online.reaconverter.com) one are able to convert. But I need to do it inside a console application. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Here is a [cmp file](https://ufile.io/vbxccm2i) for reference.

Comment: what is that "CMP format"? can you point at a specification? is it proprietary? have you tried imagemagick?

Comment: I can't find much information on it... here is a link giving very brief information about it. https://www.reaconverter.com/convert/cmp.html

Comment: curious. in gerbers... the extension merely distinguishes layers, but the files are all the same vector format. -- your file's header says "Lead" so I'm... *led* to believe it's this: http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/CMP

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785790/old-image-fileformat